# Hot Reloading Page in React 17.0.2 within a container doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

If I run locally `run start`

Everything works perfectly.

After executing the command
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v ${pwd}:/app b88c46febae5

I get an unresponsive server which is just stuck. I cannot terminate it by pressing CTRL + C

What I did....

Created .env file in a root project and inserted (in any order, separately, together, with a command npm start, etc.) None of the above worked for me.

```
FAST_REFRESH=false
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

```
package.json
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "5.0.0"
```

If I enter into a running container and watch those changes in the file I edited in my IDE - they've been applied.

Windows 10 with WSL 2

Here's a brief video
https://sendvid.com/y0qbl7bl

Comment: you have to edit it within the same operating system that is hosting your server to receive the events.

Comment: Thanks mate! Moving the project to a linux environment did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me and I solved it by **disabling the wsl2 backend** in Docker (Settings > Resources > Disable that checkbox). Now I'm using Hyper V instead, and it works (though Docker UI says it is legacy).

Btw, when I converted Docker Desktop to use wls2 as the backend, it seemed to have deleted all my images, but once I converted it back they were there.

Another possible solution, mentioned in the question's comments, is moving the project folder to a location inside the Linux WSL2 filesystem. If my "legacy" solution eventually stop working, it will be the next thing I'll try.